# Basic Team foundation server questions

Tags: tfs

We use Team Foundation Server (in VS 2010)...

1. But how can I generate a list that contains the information which person checked-out currently which file?
2. Situation:
   Person "A" checked-out some files (and changed them), left the company but didnt checked-in / undo!
   How can Person "B" "undo" the changes of person "A"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to the Visual Studio command line and do the following to get a list of items checked out:

   tf.exe status /user:PersonA
2. If you are using TFS and allowing multiple people to checkout the same file then you don't need to undo their checkout as their changes will never be committed and therefore never harm you.  However, if you just want it to look "clean" and undo their changes you can use the following command:

   tf.exe undo /workspace; /server: item

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Thats what I was lokking for! BTW: Can you advice me some good tfs books? Thx!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not much of a bookworm.  I just use the interwebs for everything.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Status Sidekicks of [TFS Sidekicks tool](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) to view all the pending changes at one place and to you can undo the changes which are checked out by other users as well.

Comment: I had to uninstall Sidekicks after it repeatedly broke VS2010. Back to the command line for me :-(